# How can I make System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME") UTF-8 compatible when my username is non ascii?

Tags: c#, windows, encoding, utf-8

In my C# Windows application, I am fetching the username from `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME")` whereas my system account is non ascii, so while I debug I was getting username as "????", the name getting altered.

In windows, I tried enabling beta utf8 Unicode. It worked with that,  but it is a global setting and not only for my application. I don't want that, how can I make the `GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME")` UTF8 compatible?

Comment: Are you sure it is not just your debugger that cannot display the name? Due to the font not having the correct characters? C#, and most of windows, uses UTF16. So I would not expect issues with non ascii characters.

Comment: How or with what do you look at the variable? Debugger window, Console.Write, some Debuglog feature etc.

Comment: @JonasH i have added the debug logs for this piece of code in application , i seen GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME") returning ???.

Comment: @Ralf added debug logs and seen

Comment: @JonasH is it because of System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable relies on older Windows APIs that often don't handle UTF-8 characters correctly???

Comment: While there are ASCII windows APIs for backward compatibility, .Net have been UTF16 from the start, so there is no reason for it to use any ASCII APIs. I would suspect the problem is with whatever method you are printing your string.

Comment: @Zayn Where did you add debug logs? We still can't see from where or how you look at the content of the Environment Variable. We only know the facility you use shows you ???? and we can just assume you have a viewing problem but can't help because you don't say how you look at the content.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your output encoding is set to ASCII. Try using this before sending output:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

And here's a little console test app you may find handy:

```
using System
using System.Text;

public static class ConsoleOutputTest {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            Console.Write(Strings.ChrW(i));
            if (i % 50 == 0) { // break every 50 chars
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: The piece of code i got it from my application, it is not console app

Comment: @Zayn joe mama provided a proof-of-concept. It doesn't matter whether your app is a console app or not. Just adapt his example to see if his solution works. You won't get a copy-paste solution here since we are not developing apps for you. We are just pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction), C# strings are internally encoded as UNICODE UTF-16 characters.

The following example shows that UNICODE strings can be written to and retrieved from the Environment without special precautions:

```c#
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TryText("Hello");
    TryText("你好");
    TryText(" ");
}

static void TryText(string text1) 
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TryText", text1);
    PrintChars(text1);
    string text2 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TryText");
    PrintChars(text2);
    Console.WriteLine($"Strings are {(text1.Equals(text2) ? "unchanged" : "different!")}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

//  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction
static void PrintChars(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\"{s}\".Length = {s.Length}");
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"s[{i}] = '{s[i]}' ('\\u{(int)s[i]:x4}')");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You could use the `PrintChars()` routine to find out what happens to your variable contents.